# 401 error accessing SharePoint in Firefox on mac

Tags: error, 401, firefox

I'm currently getting a 401 error when I try to access my SharePoint site on Firefox on mac. Usually when I login on a windows computer using FF I'm prompted to enter credentials, but for some reason I am not prompted on the mac? Does anyone know how I can get it to prompt for credentials?

Update: The mac is not connect to the domain, but it is connect to the network through wifi.

Comment: try to open the site collection this way...http://sitecollectionurl.com/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true   and it will ask you for different credential...then try to provide the correct user name and passowrd...share the test result.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE It still jumps to the 401 error, without give a login prompt

Comment: really, did you copy the complete url which i mentioned..._layouts....

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yes. tried it on the the root site, the site collection I'm trying to access, and a subsite it in that collect, with no luck. e.g `http://intranet/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true` , `http://intranet/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true`, `http//intranet/sites/home/team1/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true`

Comment: what is the site collection url?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE `http://intranet/sites/home` that's the site collection I'm trying to access.

Comment: What is the authentication provider for your site ? like Windows OR ADFS with claims etc etc  ?

Comment: @Nikhil We just use windows authentication NTLM.

Comment: try this one http//intranet/sites/home/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruse‌​r=true

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Still receive the same error, and I noticed after I send the address it changes to `http://intranet/sites/home/_layouts/15/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruse‌​r=tru‌​e`

Comment: At this point I think I'm stuck using safari. Since Chrome doesn't work with our site.

Comment: Run this PS script :$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.UseSessionCookies = $true
$sts.Update()
iisreset

Comment: I suggest you to check the setting in your system.. Because this was happened with me before.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clear your credentials in Firefox?  From settings, go to the security tab, click Saved Passwords, and delete the password for your SharePoint site.

Comment: I currently do not have any passwords saved.